# Выдавать ошибку, в случае, если юзер вводит в сортируемый массив символ или мусор типа 1w2d

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void quickSort(int *numbers, int left, int right) // ф-ия сортировки Хоара в ней все в порядке.
{
  int re;
  int l = left;
  int r = right;
  re = numbers[left];
  while (left < right)
  {
    while ((numbers[right] >= re) && (left < right))
      right--;
    if (left != right)
    {
      numbers[left] = numbers[right];
      left++;
    }
    while ((numbers[left] <= re) && (left < right))
      left++;
    if (left != right)
    {
      numbers[right] = numbers[left];
      right--;
    }
  }
  numbers[left] = re;
  re = left;
  left = l;
  right = r;
  if (left < re)
    quickSort(numbers, left, re - 1);
  if (right > re)
   quickSort(numbers, re + 1, right);
}
int main() // В мейне предлагаю ввести сортируемый массив. Суть в том, что 
юзер вводит через консоль нужное ему кол-во элементов, нажимает пробел, и 
начинается сортировка. А мне нужно чтобы выдавало ошибку, как только юзер 
вводит символ или мусор по типу "1q2we" а не пропускало только 1. В этом и 
заключается моя проблема, не знаю как реализовать, очень долго мучаюсь.
{
  int i=0, y=0, x=0, t=0;
  int b[100];
cin >> noskipws;
  cout<<"Vvedite ot 5 do 20 elementov" <<endl;
  while(cin >> x)
    {
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    i++;
    b[i]=x;
    y++;
    }
  quickSort(b, 0, y);
     for (int i = 0; i<y; i++)
   {
        cout<<b[i+1]<<" ";
        t++;
   }

  if ( t<5 )
 cout<<"Error, vi vveli menee 5-i elementov" << endl;
 if ( t>20 )
 cout<<"Error, vi vveli bolee 20-i elementov" << endl;
system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Прочитать ввод как строку, затем использовать x=stoi(s,p). Проверить p - если прочитана вся введенная строка - ввод был целым числом, иначе - содержал мусор.

Comment: Или вот еще https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087530/8491726 два варинта реализации ввода с валидацией

Answer (score 0):

Используй isdigit() для проверки.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, нагляднее. Я пробовал использовать эту ф-ию, но как-то не вышло с ней

Answer (score 0):

от багов не защищено, но вот такое решение. немного сложнее, чем должно быть.
Суть в том, что тебе так или иначе весь ввод вогнать в строку, и уже строку обрабатывать на лишние символы, на разделение пробелами и прочее. Можно было просто через cin в массив char считать всё, включая пробелы, но со string проще работать имхо. Пробуй =)

```
#include <string>
```

и

```
int main()
{
  int  t=0,i=0,y=0,j=0;
  char number[10]; //для хранения отдельного числа
  int b[100];
  string c;
  cin >> noskipws;
  cout<<"Vvedite ot 5 do 20 elementov" <<endl;
  getline(cin,c,'\n');
  while(i<c.length()){
    if(!(isdigit(c[i]) || c[i]==' ' )) { //если символ не цифра,
                                         //возвращаем ошибку
                                         //та самая isdigit()
        cout<<"error: неверные символы"<<endl;
        return 1;
        }
    number[y]=c[i];
    if(c[i]==' '||i==c.length()-1){ //если встретили пробел 
                                     //или последнюю цифру
        b[j] = atoi(number);        //преобразуем массив символов в 
                                    //число
        y=0; //возвращаем индекс в начало массива number
        for (int s=0; s<10; s++) number[s] = 0; //обнуляем массив
        i++;
        j++;
        continue;
        }
  i++;
  y++;
  }
  quickSort(b, 0, j);
  for (int i = 0; i<j; i++){
        cout<<b[i+1]<<" ";
        t++;
   }
  cout<<endl;
  if ( t<5 )
  cout<<"Error, vi vveli menee 5-i elementov" << endl;
  if ( t>20 )
  cout<<"Error, vi vveli bolee 20-i elementov" << endl;
  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```